# Update Zoho creator record from URL

Tags: url-parameters, zoho

Is it possible to update a single Zoho creator record sending all the variables via URL? In the Zoho documentation there are instructions to open a specific form to manually update some record, but I can´t find if I can send also the values to change without showing the form.

For example in this URL
https://creator.zoho.com/zchelp/employee-manager/?Employee_ID=1234#Form:Employee

I would like to add something like this (of course this is not working):
https://creator.zoho.com/zchelp/employee-manager/?Employee_ID=1234#Form:Employee**&edit:email,value=newemail@newserver.com&successurl:www.google.com**

Answer (score 0):

I also asked the same question to Zoho support service. They sent me the following answer:

Greetings from Zoho Creator.

Unfortunately it is not possible to update records by passing the URL in the web browser without loading the form. You can however load the values for the fields of the form.

Please use the following URL as a guide 
https://creator.zoho.com/zchelp/employee-manager/#Form:Employee?Employee_ID=1234&Phone=0987656789

Are you trying to have an external service use the REST API to update records in Zoho Creator. Yes you can use the Zoho Creator REST API call for doing the same. For more information on REST API call please use the following link:

https://www.zoho.com/creator/help/api/rest-api/zoho-creator-rest-api.html

For any further questions please feel free to reply to this email, I will be glad to help you.

Hope you have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

both methods (REST API and XML API) assume POST request, that's mean that some parameter MUST come in the body of request (== hidden)